# Getting 0 for minimum value but the maximum value is okay

Tags: java

I am trying to input an array using a scanner. That part is already done. Now, I am tasked to get the maximum and minimum numbers from my input. I was able to get the maximum but with the minimum, it is returning 0.

Is there a misplacement of syntax perhaps?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int in;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of elements you want to store: ");
        in=sc.nextInt();  

        int array[] = new int[in];

        int min = array[0];
        int max = array[0];

            for (int i=0; i < in; i++){
    System.out.print("Input number "+(i+1)+" :");
                array[i]=sc.nextInt();
                if(array[i]>max){
                    max=array[i];
                }
                else if (array[i]<min){
                    min=array[i];
                }                
            }
                sc.close();

    System.out.print(" The inputed array is "); 
            for (int i=0; i < in; i++){  
            System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
            }
    System.out.println("\n    --------------------");
    System.out.println("The highest number is: "+max);
    System.out.println("The lowest number is: "+ min);
        }  
    }
```

(also if you can, can y'all tell me how to get the index of the minimun and maximum value and print it?)

I tried different if and else if methods. I also tried nesting but I am getting the same outcome.

Comment: You set max/min initially (and quite unusual) to zero. So what are your test numbers, do they include negative values?

Comment: i tried initializing them that's why it was set to zero. and no, they do not include negative numbers

Comment: Also, you could replace the if/else statement by `max = Math.max(max, array[i]); min = Math.min(min, array[i]);’

Comment: If your test numbers don‘t include negative values, then the initial value of min (0) will remain the minimum.

Comment: how should I try to initialize the min and max numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare an initialize your `int` array[]:

```
int array[] = new int[in];
```

you essentially are filling each array element with 0 by default. Then, when you declare and initialize the `min` and `max` variables with `array[0]` it would be the same as declaring:

```
int min = 0;
int max = 0;
```

The `max` variable is at a relatively low value which is good **unless** the User enters all signed (negative) integer values to make up the array elements in which case **none** of those entry values will ever max over 0 which means at the end, `max` will be 0 which is also wrong.

The same theory applies to the `min` variable. Since the `min` variable already holds a low value of 0 (initialized as such), the only way an element value within the array[] Array will be lower is if the array actually contained a signed (negative) value. If it doesn't the the already held value in `min` will remain to be the lowest value...which as you know will be in most cases wrong.

The thing to do in this particular use-case would be to initialize the `min` variable with a value which would be the largest a `int` data type can hold:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

You would be pretty much guaranteed that a value within the int[] array will never exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and that if there is a element within the array that is lower, `min` will end up getting updated to that value.

The same should be applied to the initialization of the `max` variable except with the lowest possible int data type value:

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

I think at this point you can understand why. ;)

So, all in all, simply change:

```
int min = array[0];
int max = array[0];
```

to this instead:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

and all should be fine.

**On A Side:**

In a real world application where a User is expected to fill in values for an Array, there is no way of knowing what the User (like your instructor) may be entering to fill the elements of that array unless you code specifically to ensure a particular value range. By doing what is described above eliminates any worry of that unless the User supplies a value greater than what an **int** data type can accept in which case an exception would occur and the application will crash.

Comment: I see, what I got wrong is initializing or already declaring a value to min and max which is zero. I got confused at first because I am a beginner at coding and the way our instructor told us is if you want something to not hold a value that will gonna change, you can use 0 which in this case isn't applicable. Thank you so much for your help, my code is up and running.

(do you also have any advice on how to get and display the index of the max and min number after? any response will be appreciated thank you)

Comment: That's right. Because `min` was initialized as 0 from the start, there must be a value within an element of the Array being checked which contains a value LESS than 0. If there isn't one then 0 will always win as lowest. instead of provide the lowest value within the Array itself. Do your best to understand this as you will encounter this sort of situation many times throughout your career. Also, now would be a good time to read up on the [Math.min()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_min_int.htm) and [Math.max()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_max_int.htm) methods.

Comment: With your **now new** code, because the `elements` List has been sorted in ascending order, `min` would be the element value located at index **0** of the List and `max` would be the element value located at the very end of the List: `elements.size()-1`. You of course would only use those index values **after** the List is sorted.

Comment: **After** you have established what `min` and `max` are: `int minIndex = 0; int maxIndex = 0; for (int i = 0; i < unsorted.size(); i++) { if (unsorted.get(i) == min && minIndex == 0) { minIndex = i; }  if unsorted.get(i) == max && maxIndex == 0) { maxIndex = i; } }`.  This If there are duplicate values within the `unsorted` List then the provided for` loop above *should* retrieve only the first encounter of each. Let me know if this works for you. I just typed this in and it's not tested...There might be a typo. Use `minIndex` and `maxIndex` in any of your `System.out...`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will definitely read the links you provided. I really appreciate the time answering and catering my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int in;
        List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of elements you want to store: ");
        in=sc.nextInt();

        for (int i=0; i < in; i++){
            System.out.print("Input number "+(i+1)+" :");
            elements.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        sc.close();

        List<Integer> unsorted = new ArrayList<>(elements);
        Collections.sort(elements);

        int max = elements.get(elements.size()-1);
        int min = elements.get(0);

        System.out.println("\n    --------------------");
        System.out.println("The highest number is: "+max);
        System.out.println("The lowest number is: "+ min);
        System.out.println("Index of Min Value is : "+unsorted.indexOf(min));
        System.out.println("Index of Max Value is : "+unsorted.indexOf(max));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the respond. the min, max, as well as the indexes were found by using array list, correct?

Comment: `yeah correct.`

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing min even before taking inputs. That's why the min value is always 0 because the default initial value of int array is 0. So, the `else if (array[i]<min)` condition is never met because no non-negative integer can be smaller than 0.

You can try adding this in your for loop AFTER you take inputs:

```
if(i==0){
min = array[0];
max = array[0];
}
```

Comment: thank you, I got it by placing the declaration or initialization of min and max after taking in inputs. Thank you so much!


Is there a way to get the index and display the index of the min and max number?

Comment: Create two other variables minIndex and maxIndex. Then assign their values accordingly when finding min and max.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use type Integer (instead of int), as they can be initialized by `null`

```
Integer max = null;
Integer min = null;
```

In your loop:

```
if(max == null || max < array[i]) {
  max = array[i];
}

if(min == null || min > array[i]) {
  min = array[i];
}
```